# How do we get figure references to not render as "??"

Tags: errors, cross-referencing, ref

Below is some source code for a short/brief document. When I compile the short document document only once, the source code `\ref{figure:FORMULA:anatomy}` becomes `??` in the pdf. If I run PDFLaTeX a second time, the `.aux` files etc... get updated and the figure reference becomes `1.1`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}                            
\begin{document}                             

\section{Yellow}
\subsection{Submarines}

blah blah \ref{figure:FORMULA:anatomy}. 

\begin{figure}[htpb] \label{figure:FORMULA:anatomy}
  \centering
   \fbox{
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{FORMULA_anatomy}
            \caption{I'm a caption}
        \end{minipage}
    }% end fbox
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

I have a different document which after running through PDFLaTeX a dozen times still has the figure references showing as `??`. How can I get the figure references to render properly? Its very long document, so I will provide a [link](https://textuploader.com/1awpb) to the source code rather than pasting in the body of this question.

### The source code for the document for which `\ref{lable}` almost always becomes `??` is [here](https://textuploader.com/1awpb)

Comment: You must place the `\label` after the `\caption`.

Comment: Oh my, how many times do we have this question?